# LeetCode 552: Student Attendance Record II

Tags: code-golf, math, tips

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem copied here. If you have time and would like to golf for a short solution, please do so.

#### Requirement

- It has to only pass the LeetCode's Online Judge, if the language would be available.
- If the language is not available, simply we should possibly keep the `class Solution` as well as the function name.

#### Languages and Version Notes

Available languages are:

- C++ clang 9 Uses the C++17 standard.
- Java    13.0.1
- Python  2.7.12
- Python3 3.8
- C   gcc 8.2
- C#  8.0
- JavaScript 14.3.0
- Ruby    2.4.5
- Bash    4.3.30
- Swift   5.0.1
- Go  1.13
- Scala   2.13
- Kotlin  1.3.10
- Rust    1.40.0
- PHP 7.2

Thank you!

### Problem

> Given a positive integer n, return the number of all possible
> attendance records with length n, which will be regarded as
> rewardable. The answer may be very large, return it after mod 10 ^ 9 + 7.
>
> A student attendance record is a string that only contains the
> following three characters:
>
> - 'A' : Absent.
> - 'L' : Late.
> - 'P' : Present.
>
> A record is regarded as rewardable if it doesn't contain more than one
> 'A' (absent) or more than two continuous 'L' (late).
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> - Input: n = 2
> - Output: 8
>
> #### Explanation:
>
> There are 8 records with length 2 will be regarded as rewardable:
>
> - "PP" , "AP", "PA", "LP", "PL", "AL", "LA", "LL"
> - Only "AA" won't be regarded as rewardable owing to more than one absent times.
> - Note: The value of n won't exceed 100,000.

#### Accepted Code

```
class Solution:
    def checkRecord(self, n):
        MOD = 1000000007
        a = b = d = 1
        c = e = f = 0
        for _ in range(n - 1):
            a, b, c, d, e, f = (a + b + c) % MOD, a, b, (a + b + c + d + e + f) % MOD, d, e

        return (a + b + c + d + e + f) % MOD
```

#### Accepted Golf Attempt in Python 3 - 185 bytes - I

```
class Solution:
    def checkRecord(self,n):
        M=1000000007;a=b=d=1;c=e=f=0
        for _ in range(n-1):a,b,c,d,e,f=(a+b+c)%M,a,b,(a+b+c+d+e+f)%M,d,e
        return(a+b+c+d+e+f)%M
```

#### Accepted Golf Attempt in Python 3 - 185 bytes - II

```
class Solution:
    def checkRecord(self,n):
        M=int(1e9+7);a=b=d=1;c=e=f=0
        for _ in range(n-1):a,b,c,d,e,f=(a+b+c)%M,a,b,(a+b+c+d+e+f)%M,d,e
        return(a+b+c+d+e+f)%M
```

#### Reference

In LeetCode's answer template, there is a class usually named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename.

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/student-attendance-record-ii/discuss/)
- [Languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-)
- I guess the solution was originally designed by [Stefan Pochmann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/40544/stefan-pochmann)

Comment: I appreciate you being open with crediting the problem LeetCode and providing a link to it. But I still wonder if the site or challenge author would be OK with having the problem here. It also makes a lot of answers be easy to Google.

Comment: As a code golf challenge, this has lots of things we consider [Things to Avoid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges) on the site, with the lengthy boilerplate names and the programming chestnut of 10^7+9. It's also not ideal that to know if a solution is fast enough to pass I have to run it on another site. As a tips question, this all of course all makes sense to help you with a challenge from elsewhere. I think though that we'd do better to help if you explain how your code works and what you've tried, and limit to your one language.

Comment: This surely won't scale to inputs like n=10^6 within the needed runtime, but here's a short and nifty purely integer-arithmetic expression based on generating functions: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcaxDoMgEADQufcVtzSBs0REJxOWm5n4A5qKmtjTEJd@PWV67/rd2ymuVvaDJRothBYLED0Td9wNkP2Rvu9PQpmZKFDsVXM0URO5vlUFI2bST675LCi4C5Yk66Kc1TM8rrLLjfLCrETXPw "Python 2 – Try It Online"). This is only partly golfed and doesn't have the mod 1e9+7. For larger input `n`, you'll need `L` to at least `n`, and `B` to at least the output.

Comment: If anyone wants it, the generating function (formal power series) is pretty nice: \$(1+x+x^2)/(1-x-x^2-x^3)^2\$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tips:

1. The first argument `self` can be renamed to something shorter.
2. Use `while n:n-=1` to loop `n` times
3. (Python 2 specific) You can use a single tab for the second level of indentation, instead of 2 spaces.
4. For this problem, it's sufficiently fast to just mod `b` every loop, instead of having to mod both `a` and `d`.
5. The part `a,b,c,d,e,f=...` can be broken into `a,b,c=...;d,e,f=...`, which allows reusing the updated value `a=a+b+c`
6. `c,e,f` can be initialized to `10**9+7` instead of `0` (found by @xnor).

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>136 134 131 127</s> 125 bytes

```python
class Solution:
 def checkRecord(_,n):
	a=b=d=1;c=e=f=M=10**9+7
	while n:n-=1;a,b,c=a+b+c,a%M,b;d,e,f=a+d+e+f,d,e
	return d%M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoIwEEXX9BTdkIAdDbgxQuYIbPQApp1OA5G0pJQYT19xY3y7//7iLe80Bn/OmWa9rvIe5i1NwXdCWnaSRqbnjSlEWz3A150oNBq02PaEjA4HbJvD4aouoniN08zSd/64vxoMEGplFIEuBzC9BQa3G6tYOdiXKCKnLXppyyEvcfLpV6/q03@5bb7U@QM)

Comment: `exec('a,b,c=a+b+c,a%M,b;d,e,f=a+d+e+f,d,e;'*n)` saves 2 over the `while` loop. EDIT, actually 6 as it allows inlining too: `def checkRecord(_,n):M=10**9+7;a=b=d=1;c=e=f=0;exec('a,b,c=a+b+c,a%M,b;d,e,f=a+d+e+f,d,e;'*n);return d%M`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks, I did consider using `exec`, but it's too slow for large `n` due to the construction of really long  string.

Comment: Haven't check this on Leetcode, but it looks like you can initialize `c=e=f=M=10**9+7` since we're working mod M anyway.

Comment: @xnor That works, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't need more than one space per level of indentation.
2. Observe that you have `(a+b+c+d+e+f)` used twice. This code duplication can be avoided by running the loop one more time and using `d` of the extra iteration
3. `[0]*n` is 3 bytes shorter than `range(n)`
4. It's not necessary to modulo by 1000000007 each time; you can remove it from the loop and only do it at the end (This takes about 1 second for `n=100000` on TIO, which appears to be too slow). After this, `M` will only be used once, so you can inline it into the one place it was used

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 136 bytes

```python
class Solution:
 def checkRecord(self,n):
  a=b=d=1;c=e=f=0
  for _ in [0]*n:a,b,c,d,e,f=a+b+c,a,b,a+b+c+d+e+f,d,e
  return d%int(1e9+7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETvfsVehMYs0uJBbNmf0KOIpMmGFsumpOnBr4@NIDinmTcMzPxOQ5BTznYyywK3MK1pDNLuwLEHO7B9XdmG6KqFJ4@itgYM9eSo6Swxeao34kOEJ4wC9/pxkNZgjxYdMnoyutcWC/k67TRrX7ptFjmtUcDtR0lVwxd9VnmOJfyOVOr4f6Kpi5TKHw)

---

Or, if the last tip is too slow:

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 148 bytes

```python
class Solution:
 def checkRecord(self,n):
  M=int(1e9+7);a=b=d=1;c=e=f=0
  for _ in [0]*n:a,b,c,d,e,f=(a+b+c)%M,a,b,(a+b+c+d+e+f)%M,d,e
  return d%M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5LCsIwFNx7ircpJCZIiwux5R2hG12KSJq80NKSlDRdePqYIIKzmx8z6zuO3p1T0ovaNrj7ZY@Td@0BDFnQI@n5RtoHwzZarHQ8O9Dj5CJr6CouvFM4oMGm00hosc629QFeMDl41M@ja5UcpJZGkrTIlBiE5lUvi/plwggStmg5k@uB4h4cmKpPayhDv1OMn/4PNXUB5@kD)

Comment: @pppery you can rename `self` to something with 1 character, and remove the space after `in`: `for _ in[0]*n`. If you switch to Python 2, you can use a single tab instead of 2 spaces for the second level of indent.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum This is a [tag:tips] question, so I think that would be better as a separate answer.

Comment: @pppery gotcha, I'll post a separate answer.

Comment: You can remove the space at `in[0]` in both your functions.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen This is a [tag:tips] question, so that tip should be a separate answer. I will not be editing any other users' golfing suggestions into this answer, because I feel that defeats the point of [tag:tips].

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 121 bytes

```c
checkRecord(n){long a=1,b=1,d=1,c=0,e=0,f=0,x,y,m=7+1e9;for(;n--;d=y%m)x=a+b+c,y=x+d+e+f,f=e,e=d,c=b,b=a,a=x%m;return d;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BCsMgEEX3OYUEAooGYjeliJfouhszahpaTZAUDCFnt9PSRVftwNu9//9AOwCUAlcHt7ODKVka2Xaf4kCMlqJHLAK6Ew7xSBarCPrIpTspPyWqYtsqq9cmsKwN7zmIVWduueMeAw6DFgt6LDPC6NwEldzySJFYtZdgxkjZVs1pjIundWMvsRbf/xBJGFO/hMM/QXave1uf6U5Ve3kC)

Slightly golfed less

```c
checkRecord(n){
  long a=1,b=1,d=1,c=0,e=0,f=0,x,y,m=7+1e9;
  for(;n--;d=y%m)
    x=a+b+c,
    y=x+d+e+f,
    f=e,
    e=d,
    c=b,
    b=a,
    a=x%m;
  return d;
}
```

Comment: [116 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY5BCsIwFET3PUUoFBKSQuNGJPxLuHaT/iS1aFIJFVpKzx6/rlzpwNu9GQbbAbEUvHq8nT1O2fEktvuUBmZBq55wBEKnPBGIRa0qwlFqfzJhytyktjUO1iaKBazsJaoVFumkl4EKnoqOBnoas8rC0kRjwZm9RDsmLrbqkcc0B1437pJq9X2FaSaE@SUc/gm6e@djZT8/c2KdqfbyAg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>127</s> <s>126</s> 119 bytes

```
class Solution:
 def checkRecord(s,n):
    a=[1,0,0]
    while~n:n-=1;a=[sum(a[:3])]+a;b=a[3]=sum(a[1:7])%(10**9+7)
    return b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY1BC8IgGEDP81d4Cfy2FdoOI4d/oo7Dg3PGpKVDHdGlv25FBN16x8eDt9zT5N0@Zz2rGPHJz2uy3nGER3PGejL6cjTah5HE2gFHhRI9q2lNJSpuk53Nw3G3Fax7@bheiep5I0FWqhuE6hspPpLxVsKGMFqWh6oFVAST1uDwkJdgXSLfL4Hd75NRAPSneAOQnw) Somewhat slower than @SurculoseSputum's answer. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen. Saved a further 7 bytes thanks to @xnor.

Out of interest, I also wrote a 34-byte solution in [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal):

```
≔Ｅ⁶¬ιηＦＮＵＭη⎇﹪λ³§η⊖λΣ…η⁺³λＩ﹪Ση⁺⁷Ｘφ³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LCsIwEEX3fkWWE4igFHTRVYmbLloK@gMxSU0hj5KH2q@PiehsZjHn3LlcMc8d0zl3ISwPCwNb4UTQ6CIsGBOkcLubnUfQ2zXFMZm79IAxKhx1xjArQBF0k94yv8HgRNIONEFNcbvYWyHfFbhI7qWRNkoBuuZekwG6cS2pcmslJp0CNASVa5l2N/nFRqAsxH9qVRT@keey3at0meuvr5Lz8ZD3T/0B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅ⁶¬ιη
```

Create an array of six elements where only the first element is `1` and the others are all `0`.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop over the given number of times.

```
ＵＭη
```

Modify the array in-place according to the result of the mapping (the mapping is calculated first, then the array modified).

```
⎇﹪λ³
```

For positions 1, 2, 4 and 5:

```
§η⊖λ
```

Take the previous element of the previous array.

```
Σ…η⁺³λ
```

Otherwise take the sum of the array so far plus the next three elements.

This results in `h = [sum(h[0:3]), h[0], h[1], sum(h), h[3], h[4]]`.

```
Ｉ﹪Ση⁺⁷Ｘφ³
```

Take the final sum and reduce modulo `7+1000**3`.

Comment: You can remove the space at `in[0]` for -1 in the Python function.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen ... I was just pasting that in, but I'll be generous and credit you anyway.

Comment: Nice solution, here's a couple more saves: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1BC8IgGIDh8/wVXgK/rWI2YuTwT9RRPDhnbLQ@hzqiS3/dggi6vu/hWZ5p9HjI2c4mRnrx85omj4LQwV2pHZ29nZ31YWBxiyBIYaTiulK1Lo@keIzT7F4ocCd59zlxvTOjRKNBV6brpVGNlt/IRathw3hdlqeqBVIEl9aAtM9LmDCxn8xg/6/yGiC/AQ "Python 2 – Try It Online") (fixed)

Comment: 119: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY1BC8IgGEDP81d4Cfy2FdoOI4d/oo7Dg3PGpKVDHdGlv25FBN16x8eDt9zT5N0@Zz2rGPHJz2uy3nGER3PGejL6cjTah5HE2gFHhRI9q2lNJSpuk53Nw3G3Fax7@bheiep5I0FWqhuE6hspPpLxVsKGMFqWh6oFVAST1uDwkJdgXSLfL4Hd75NRAPSneAOQnw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Does TLE mean it took too long? Ran out of memory?

Comment: @Emma You can make it much faster at a cost of 4 bytes by adding `[:5]`: after the `+a`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 137 bytes

```
long checkRecord(int n){long a=1,b=1,c=0,d=1,e=0,f=0,x,y,m=7+(int)1e9;for(;n-->0;y=x+d+e+f,f=e,e=d,c=b,b=a,a=x%m,d=y%m)x=a+b+c;return d;}
```

Figured I'd add a Java answer, since it was missing. It's a straightforward port of [*@ceilingcat*'s C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206422/52210), since I couldn't find anything shorter.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TU9BasMwELznFXsJSMg28qkUofygl@ZYSllLcqrEkoIspzbGb3e3OXVhGNidGXau@MD6am@7GXAc4Q19XPchxQuYb2du786kbJmPBSJfn3vUbdURjJaVJXbEPWGuliroF/En5q17VX3KTMW6Pkm16FlY4URPSkcOS@6OUrBCPR8D5SzHwGeNohNGZVemHMGqbQe4T93gDYwFC9EjeQuBnmTnkn28fHwC8vUANOdlLC40aSrNnU5liCy6n2cjxpv/bVopv6SUnCsybodt/wU)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>24</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
6LΘIFÐÁr3£‚O30Sǝ}O9°7+%
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//zZMzphJRsOQw4FyM8Kj4oCaTzMwU8edfU85wrA3KyX//zEw)

**Explanation:**

```python
6L                # Push the list [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  Θ               # Check == 1 for each (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey): [1,0,0,0,0,0]
   IF             # Loop the input amount of times:
     Ð            #  Triplicate the list at the top of the stack
      Á           #  Rotate the top list once towards the right: [f,a,b,c,d,e]
       r          #  Reverse the stack so this rotated list is at the bottom
        3£        #  Pop and push the first three items of the top list: [a,b,c]
          ‚       #  Pair it with the full list: [[a,b,c,d,e,f],[a,b,c]]
           O      #  Sum both inner lists: [a+b+c+d+e+f,a+b+c]
            30S   #  Push [3,0]
               ǝ  #  Insert the a+b+c+d+e+f and a+b+c at indices 3 and 0 respectively in
                  #  the rotated list: [a+b+c,a,b,a+b+c+d+e+f,d,e]
    }O            # After the loop, sum the resulting list
      9°          # Push 10 to the power 9: 1000000000
        7+        # Add 7: 1000000007
          %       # Modulo
                  # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86_64 machine language for Linux, 83 bytes

```
0x00:  55                push rbp
0x01:  45 31 C0          xor  r8d, r8d
0x04:  31 C9             xor  ecx, ecx
0x06:  53                push rbx
0x07:  6A 01             push 1
0x09:  41 5A             pop  r10
0x0b:  31 DB             xor  ebx, ebx         ; a=b=d=0
0x0d:  4D 89 D1          mov  r9, r10
0x10:  4D 89 D3          mov  r11, r10         ; c=e=f=1
0x13:  BE 07 CA 9A 3B    mov  esi, 0x3b9aca07  ; m=1000000007
0x18:  4B 8D 04 0B       lea  rax, [r11 + r9]
0x1c:  48 01 C8          add  rax, rcx         ; x=a+b+c
0x1f:  48 99             cqo  
0x21:  49 8D 0C 02       lea  rcx, [r10 + rax]
0x25:  48 F7 FE          idiv rsi              ; x%=m
0x28:  4C 01 C1          add  rcx, r8
0x2b:  48 01 D9          add  rcx, rbx         ; y=x+d+e+f
0x2e:  4C 89 C3          mov  rbx, r8          ; f=e
0x31:  48 89 C8          mov  rax, rcx         ; e=d
0x34:  4C 89 C9          mov  rcx, r9          ; c=b
0x37:  48 89 D5          mov  rbp, rdx         ; b=a
0x3a:  48 99             cqo  
0x3c:  48 F7 FE          idiv rsi              ; y%=m
0x3f:  4D 89 D0          mov  r8, r10
0x42:  4D 89 D9          mov  r9, r11
0x45:  49 89 D2          mov  r10, rdx         ; d=y
0x48:  49 89 EB          mov  r11, rbp         ; a=x
0x4b:  FF CF             dec  edi
0x4d:  75 C9             jne  0x18             ; if( --n ) goto 0x18
0x4f:  92                xchg eax, edx
0x50:  5B                pop  rbx
0x51:  5D                pop  rbp
0x52:  C3                ret                   ; return d
```

To [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/PSsQwEMbv@xSlIKTiQtIkNkPxDTx5ziWZSdZl3a50KwTFV7dO6sWTzunj@/ODwf0BcV3FLT4nPD0lvMzUie7hsfUFpVbGWuvLfbAaQStftLLBKMmKlANDFH2JiXTVnEYIGOTgi4zSODKcGodOKuPYQ3YAwJec8mCc7LeUaQZ9YQISVDI61g71lkL1fQF2yDreGvpZbwsiWT3qWQNVck6xal70CIPFzDxtycZ2XM/hOInuY/c6H6cli/aG/NTe/fpcNKrpuvGvQv9fQcl6W2tOy9s8NXLcfa5fmF/C4bru31NJeF0Cnr4B), call the following c code as if it were a function (you may also be able to paste it into one or more 'interview preparation websites' and run it as if it were a c program)

```
(*checkRecord)()=L"\xc0314555\x6a53c931\x315a4101\xd1894ddb\xbed3894d\x3b9aca07\x0b048d4b\x48c80148\x0c8d4999\xfef74802\x48c1014c\x894cd901\xc88948c3\x48c9894c\x9948d589\x4dfef748\x894dd089\xd28949d9\xffeb8949\x92c975cf\xc35d5b";
```